# Regex to replace a character if is unique

Tags: regex, sed

I need please help with a script with a regex to fix a big text file under linux (with sed for example). My records looks like:

```
1373350|Doe, John|John|Doe|||B|Acme corp|...
1323350|Simpson, Homer|Homer|Simpson|||3|Moe corp|...
```

I need to validate if the 7th column has a unique character (maybe a letter or number) and if true, add the second column without the comma, i mean:

```
1373350|Doe, John|John|Doe|||B Doe John|Acme corp|...
1323350|Simpson, Homer|Homer|Simpson|||3 Simpson Homer|Moe corp|...
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: What does "unique character" mean in this context? No other row has the same character in that position?

Comment: If Etan is understanding you correctly: no regular expression can extract info about some *other string* entirely. You'll probably need to write a little script to do this for you.

Comment: You could use awk if you are using unix. The "unique character"  part is still unclear though.

Comment: Hi all. "Unique character" is a simple character, one letter or number.

Comment: If the 7th field has a word or phrase, nothing is done. If the 7th field is only a letter (uppercase, lowercase or number), must proceed with the replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awk is better suited for this job:

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS = FS } length($7) == 1 { x = $2; sub(/,/, "", x); $7 = $7 " " x } 1' filename
```

That is:

```
BEGIN { OFS = FS }   # output separated the same way as the input
length($7) == 1 {    # if the 7th field is one character long
  x = $2             # make a copy of the second field
  sub(/,/, "", x)    # remove comma from it
  $7 = $7 " " x      # append it to seventh field
}
1                    # print line
```